# How can I ensure a token doesn't expire between preflight calls?

Tags: javascript, keycloak

I'm facing an intermittent problem with Keycloak. If a user triggers a preflight API call and Keycloak's token expires between that and the actual API call, the preflight call will return a 200, but the real API call will return a 401 (as the token has now expired).

The flow of events is essentially:

1. User triggers preflight API call, generating an OPTIONS request.
2. Keycloak's token expires and is refreshed.
3. Preflight request returns, GET call is sent out with old Keycloak token.
4. The API returns a 401 as the old token has expired.

Here is what it looks like in my browser's Network tab:

[image: Example Network tab flow]

How can I ensure the Keycloak token doesn't expire between these events?

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
async onTokenExpired() {
  this.token = await this.updateToken();
  this.updateHeaders();
}

updateHeaders() {
  http.setHeaders({
    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`
  });
}

updateToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.keycloak.updateToken()
      .success(() => {
        resolve(this.keycloak.token);
      })
      .error(reject);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution I ended up going with for this involves calling Keycloak's `updateToken` method every time an API call is made, passing in a *minValidity* of 20 seconds.

> #### updateToken(minValidity)
>
> If the token expires within minValidity seconds (minValidity is optional, if not specified 5 is used) the token is refreshed. If the session status iframe is enabled, the session status is also checked.
>
> — [Keycloak's `updateToken` documentation](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html#_updatetoken_minvalidity).

My API-calling code now looks like this:

```
post(...) {
  this.keycloak.updateToken(20).success(() => {
    fetch(...)
  })
}
```

In pseudo-code, this essentially does the following:

```
When the post method is called:
  Attempt to update the token if it is going to expire within the next 20 seconds.
  If that is successful (regardless of whether it updated or not), call the API.
```

I don't believe this to be a *perfect* solution, as I'm sure there may be an instance where a preflight request takes longer than 20 seconds to execute, however in that situation this isn't really the cause of that problem and would need to be resolved on the server-side. If preflight requests frequently take longer than 20 seconds to execute, the *minValidity* can be upped to a longer duration. 20 itself is already very lenient (the default value is 5).